# PHP merging two images creates a pink shade

Tags: php, image

I am trying to merge two images using PHP code below:

```
$image1=imagecreatefrompng($url1);
$image2=imagecreatefrompng($url2);
$final = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($final, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($final, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
imagecopy($final, $image1, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagecopy($final, $image2, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
```

After merging, I get a pink shade on the generated images. Please help. How can I resolve it?

Original images:

[image: Original image 1][image: Original image 2]

Resulting merged image:

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: Please include (or at link to) copies of the original and generated (merged) images.  This is a visual question, we are going to need to see the images to known what is going on.

Comment: Looks like there might be some green sneaking in there, too. What happens if you use imagecopyresampled?

Comment: some green sneaking in there, too ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your target image is GIF, which is limited to a 256 colour palette. Try exporting as JPG or PNG and you'll probably get better colour fidelity.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code using your image link
and its works well and generates appropriate png 
For your reference

```
$url1 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDYTM.png';
$url2 ='https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKTcb.png';
$image1=imagecreatefrompng($url1);
$image2=imagecreatefrompng($url2);
$final = imagecreatetruecolor(275, 275);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($final, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($final, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
imagecopy($final, $image1, 0,0,0,0,275,275);
imagecopy($final, $image2, 0,0,0,0,275,275);
header('Content-type:image/png');
imagepng($final);
```

For gif image you can replace last two line with

```
header('Content-type:image/gif');
imagegif($final);
```